# Finite presentation of Weil algebras

Tags: commutative-algebra, synthetic-differential-geometry

Below is a picture of an excerpt of Lavendhomme's book on synthetic differential geometry.

I'm confused about the "structure constants" $\gamma_{ij}^k$. Initially I thought the superscript $k$ is just an index and not an exponent, and that these are the coordinate vectors of the products $e_i\cdot e_j$. Now I'm no longer certain. Which is it?

[image]

Comment: Why are you no longer certain?

Comment: Writing the third index as a superscript and not a subscript is traditional in these cases to make for an easier reading and not overload the notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an index. The reason it's a superscript is to indicate that it has a different variance from the subscripts.